# How to add a String to ValueExpresion programatically

Tags: jsf

Hi I'm trying to add a string value to a value expresion.
In my xhtml code sometimes i used to do things like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.value} %" />
```

it is an easy way to add '%' symbol to outputText.

How can I accomplish it programatically.

I'm able to add a value expresion:

```
final HtmlOutputText outputText = JSFUtils.createComponent(HtmlOutputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
final ValueExpression exp = JSFUtils.valueExpresion("gasto.porcentajeTotal");
outputText.setValueExpresion("value", exp);
```

but i don't know how to add '%' symbol

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a good approach, the 'setter' that needs to be called by the inputText is invalid then. The full value of the inputText needs to refer to a field, "#{myBean.value} %" is not a reference to a setter.

Comment: Programmatically or not, this will indeed always end up with a `PropertyNotWritableException`. So your statement *"In my xhtml code sometimes i used to do things like this"* is actually invalid. This is technically impossible on input fields.

Comment: Yes BalusC, you are totally right. I edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in your utility method, that it does not allow specifying `#{` and `}` because it already "automatically" wraps it. If you move the responsibility to the caller, then you should be able to achieve the task.

Below the canonical way to create a value expression ([copied](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.3/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/util/Components.java#L1035) from [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org/) [`Components`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Components)):

```
public static ValueExpression createValueExpression(String expression, Class<?> type) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(
        context.getELContext(), expression, type);
}
```

This can be used as:

```
ValueExpression ve = createValueExpresion("#{myBean.value} %", String.class);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @BalusC. I Upvoted your answer :)